# Laravel failed to load resources (404)

Tags: laravel, permissions

I have a Laravel application and in my public/js folder I have some javascript files. When running my application at 127.0.0.1:8000/ Laravel can't open the JS-files. Error 404:

```
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"
```

I thought it could be something with authentication so I already did a chmod 777 on the public/js folder. But that didn't help.

I import them like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/slider-custom.css') }}">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/search-form/range-slider.js') }}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/provider-search.js') }}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/search-form/show-detail.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: How are you referencing/calling the files in blade?

Comment: if the file is compiled with versioning, then you need to call `mix('app.js')` to get its true path

Comment: could you post some of the code where you are including these scripts?

Comment: edited my question!

Comment: Did you try `{{ asset('js/jquery.min.js') }}`?  Also whats the user of the file? Make sure its not just has correct permissions but has correct owner(e.g. no root but www-data)?

Comment: @MihirBhende how you mean, the user? just working at localhost. thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-asset

Use the Asset helper:

```
<script src="{{asset('js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
```

Your architecture will be like:

> project/public/js/your JSs files

Comment: Changed it in my code. 
like: 
    <script src="{{asset('/js/scripts.js')}}"></script>

Comment: still app can't find it. If I inspect the page, the path to the files are correct like:
https://127.0.0.1:8000/public/js/name.js

Answer (score 1):

don't use / before js  try this

```
<script src="{{asset('js/scripts.js')}}"></script>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. There are two js folders, I mistakenly put the customfile.js in resources/js director when it's supposed to be in public/js directory.

This fixed my problem.